# Custom Pages with Wordpress 3.4.1

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having some problems trying to get a custom page to display on my site. What I want is to create a page where the client can edit the content in Wordpress. When I add the page using the Wordpress "add new page" it doesn't show, but if I create a page in .php with the same content, it works fine. This is what I did:

First I created a blank .php template called lefthome.php using the following code:

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: Left Template
*/
?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'page' ); ?>
```

I then went into Wordpress, clicked on pages > add new. I gave my page a title and added the content I wanted to appear on the page. Then from the template option in the page attributes I choose the template I had earlier created (Left Template) and clicked update.

I wanted this template to appear on the homepage, so I tried to add it to the homepage template I had created using the following code:

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: Home
*/

get_header(); ?>

<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/slider.php'); ?>

<div id="content">
    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/lefthome.php'); ?>
</div>

        <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'page' ); ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The header, slider.php and footer all show fine. The contents of the lefthome.php do not appear. I do not know how to get it to show. The only way I have got it to show is to paste the contents into the lefthome.php template. I don't want to do this though, as the client will not be able to edit the contents themselves.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to display the content of a page just by calling directly its template file. You need to query the page itself. In that matter it won't matter what template you've already assigned to it anymore.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home
*/

get_header(); ?>

<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/slider.php'); ?>

<div id="content">
<?php
global $post;
$page_id =5; // 5 is the id of the page we want to present with Left Template.
$post = get_post( $page_id );

setup_postdata( $post );
include locate_template( 'lefthome.php' );
wp_reset_postdata(); // we are done with that. reset the query so the rest don't mess up
?>
</div>

        <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'page' ); ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this hasn't worked. I have copied it just as you put it and changed the get_post number from 5 to 54 (this is the number of the template in Wordpress) and I get the following error: Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in C:\wamp\www\beautify\wp-content\themes\beautify\home.php on line 13. I dont know what I did wrong.

Comment: my bad, store the id in a variable first. `$page_id = 5;` and use that

Comment: I am very grateful for your help, but I really do not have an idea where to place this variable. Would it be possible for you to show me exactly what I need to do? Does the number 5 relate to the post id? I don't know much about php. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it is still not showing the contents. I have changed the 5 to 54 which is the page id, but nothing shows up. I only get the edit text. The contents shows on its own when you click view page in the admin area, but not when I include the code you have written in my home.php template.

Comment: @legacyterror What do you mean by you only get the edit text?

Comment: I mean when you are logged in to wordpress you get the text that always you to edit and go to the dashboard. This is all i can see.

Comment: I have found out that Wordpress cannot display multiple pages on a single page without being told how to do it. Is there a loop or php code that can make Wordpress display more than one page on a template? I would like the lefthome.php to be displayed on the homepage.

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been searching to figure out how to do this for a while now!